# Carpeta de proyectos en Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Que tal compañeros estoy siguiendo un tutorial para realizar un CRUD con .net6 y SQL server pero al crear mi proyecto las carpetas que se crean por default no me aparecen(modelo,vista,controlador,www,etc) solo aparece la solución como se muestra en la imagen.
ya le di reparar a VS, lo desinstale y lo volví a instalar y sigue igual.
saben como puedo reparlo o a que se debe?
Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas seguro que estas creando el mismo tipo de proyecto? eso parece un proyecto vacio....

Comment: Si,sigo los pasos tal y como lo muestra el video, en otra lap hago lo mismo y si me aparecen las carpetas no se por que en la mia no me salen

Comment: Mas que reparar, instalaste las plantillas necesarias?

Comment: Plantillas?, ammm no creo que no

Comment: Tu instalacion parece estar incompleta entonces.. mas que repararla, debes instalar las cosas completas...

Comment: me puedes decir por favor, donde marco esa opcion  o  como lo hago?

Comment: Al instalar seleccionas lenguajes y frameworks a utilizar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las plantillas permiten crear un proyecto con los archivos correspondientes, en teoría puedes armar un proyecto de forma manual, pero es algo difícil. .Net es un framework que sirve para casi todo, porque lo que hay muchos tipos de proyectos y plantillas.

Además existe algo llamado "La Solución", una Solución tiene entre cero y muchos proyecto, es decir es una agrupación de proyectos. En tu imagen, lo que muestras es una solución con cero proyectos. Los paso son sencillos

**1.- Crear proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2.- Buscar la plantilla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**3.- Asignar el nombre del proyecto**

Si te fijas, al crear el primer proyecto se crea la solución que lo contiene con el mismo nombre. La última opción te permite cambiar el nombre de la solución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**4.- Configuracioenes adicionales**

Luego viene una pantalla con configuraciones, como la versión del framework a usar, si vas usar HTTPS y si usas docker

5.- El proyecto debería verse de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si seleccionas la Solución, click derecho -> Agregar -> Nuevo Proyecto. Puedes seguir agregando proyectos a la solución

---

**6.- Instalar nuevas características y plantillas para Visual Studio**

Con el VS abierto vas al menú "Herramientas" -> "Obtener Herramientas y Características"  Y ahí seleccionas lo que desas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojo, esta pantalla se divide en dos:

El lado izquierdo seleccionas elementos de manera global, digamos por tecnología. Y en el lado derecho hay un detalle, donde también puedes seleccionar elementos adicionales. Generalmente se utiliza para instalar elementos antiguos